# How to get most recent date (sort key) from dynamoDB table

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am working on a DynamoDB database with 50+ entries at the moment. It is built such that the partition key is the column labeled "Entry" and the sort key is the column labeled "Date". There are additional attributes related to cars on the road per country (but that is not the concern) My goal is to find the most recent date in the column and return it in my code. What function can I use to do this? I tried to check the documentation, but to many failures.

[image: Here is a picture of my table].

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', 'us-east-2')
table = dynamodb.Table('DataTable')

response = table.query(hash_key='Entry', ScanIndexForward=True, Limit=1)
items = response['Items']
print(items)
```

Above is my code thus far. I'd appreciate any help I can get. Once again, I just want to return the date-stamp as a result of this code.

Comment: For a given `Entry` you want the most recent date? Or just from the entire Table? If the later, I don't think there is something better than `scan` for the entire table.

Comment: I want the most recent date from the entire table. What would be the best way about doing this?